# git clone stuck on HTTP

Tags: git, http

I am trying to check out a repository from Github, I can use the git:// protocol, but not the http:// protocol. I would type `git clone http://github.com/ajaxorg/cloud9.git` and it would get stuck on `cloning into cloud9` Does anyone know what's wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Use `https://` instead of `http://`.

If that fails, try using something like `strace` to figure out what action it's getting stuck on.

Comment: I tried, But, this is also problematic. Is something wrong with my git config? Do I have to use sudo?

Comment: Shouldn't need to use sudo, no. It's possible that your git may not have https support, and that might be what's causing issues? Side note - is there a particular reason you don't want to use the git protocol?

Comment: Well, The particular repository has a couple of submodules that have submodules, which are using the HTTP protocol to retrieve the files. I use the git protocol to access the original repository almost all the time.

Comment: I checked if sudo would work, and it does. Is there any reason this happens? I cannot run it properly at my user level, but the root level has no troubles at all

Comment: I am facing the exact same issue. All git commands like `clone`, `push` work only with `sudo`. Any idea, what is causing this?